# Error reading from Fortran binary file

Tags: class, serialization, fortran, binaryfiles, fortran2008

I'm trying to write a short code, which stores an array of objects with the same parental class into a binary file and then reads them back. I'm using the unformatted binary output, as I find it the easiest way to do this.

My attempt is here:

```
module m
    implicit none

    type :: container
        class(a), allocatable :: item
    end type container

    type, abstract :: a
        character(20), public :: obj_type
        integer, public :: num
    contains
        procedure :: write_impl => write_a
        procedure :: read_impl => read_a

        generic            :: write(unformatted) => write_impl
        generic            :: read(unformatted)  => read_impl
    end type a

    type, extends(a) :: b
        integer, public :: num2
    contains
        procedure :: write_impl => write_b
        procedure :: read_impl => read_b
   end type b

    type, extends(a) :: c
    end type c

contains

    subroutine write_a(this, unit, iostat, iomsg)
        class(a), intent(in)    :: this
        integer, intent(in)         :: unit
        integer, intent(out)        :: iostat
        character(*), intent(inout) :: iomsg

        write(unit, iostat=iostat, iomsg=iomsg) this%num
    end subroutine write_a

    subroutine read_a(this, unit, iostat, iomsg)
        class(a), intent(inout) :: this
        integer, intent(in)         :: unit
        integer, intent(out)        :: iostat
        character(*), intent(inout) :: iomsg

        read(unit, iostat=iostat, iomsg=iomsg) this%num
    end subroutine read_a

    subroutine write_b(this, unit, iostat, iomsg)
        class(b), intent(in)    :: this
        integer, intent(in)         :: unit
        integer, intent(out)        :: iostat
        character(*), intent(inout) :: iomsg

        write(unit, iostat=iostat, iomsg=iomsg) this%num, this%num2
    end subroutine write_b

    subroutine read_b(this, unit, iostat, iomsg)
        class(b), intent(inout) :: this
        integer, intent(in)         :: unit
        integer, intent(out)        :: iostat
        character(*), intent(inout) :: iomsg

        read(unit, iostat=iostat, iomsg=iomsg) this%num, this%num2
    end subroutine read_b
end module m

program mwe
    use m

    implicit none

    class(a), allocatable :: o1, o2, o3, o4
    class(container), allocatable :: arr(:)
    integer :: i, arr_size, tmp
    character(20) :: str_tmp

    o1 = b('b', 1, 2)
    o2 = c('c', 3)

    allocate(arr(2))
    arr(1)%item = o1
    arr(2)%item = o2

    select type(t => o1)
        type is(b)
        write(*,*) t%num, t%num2
    end select

    select type(t => arr(1)%item)
        type is(b)
        write(*,*) t%num, t%num2
    end select

    write(*,*) 'Write into binary'
    ! WRITE size
    open(123, file='test5.dat', form='unformatted')
    write(123) SIZE(arr)

    do i=1,2 
        write(123) arr(i)%item%obj_type
            if(arr(i)%item%obj_type .eq. 'b') then
                select type(t => arr(i)%item)
                    type is(b)
                    write(*,*) t%num, t%num2
                    write(123) t
                end select
            else if(arr(i)%item%obj_type .eq. 'c') then
                select type(t => arr(i)%item)
                    type is(c)
                    write(*,*) t%num
                    write(123) t
                end select
            end if
    end do
    close(123)

    write(*,*) 'Read from binary'
    open(123, file='test5.dat', form='unformatted')
    read(123) arr_size
    write(*,*) 'array size: ', arr_size

    do i=1,2
        read(123) str_tmp
        write(*,*) str_tmp
        if(allocated(o3)) deallocate(o3)
        if(str_tmp .eq. 'b') then
            allocate(b :: o3)
            select type(t => o3)
                type is(b)
                read(123) t%num, t%num2  ! ERROR
                write(*,*) t%num, t%num2
            end select
        else if(str_tmp .eq. 'c') then
            allocate(c :: o3)
            select type(t => o3)
                type is(c)
                read(123) t%num
                write(*,*) t%num
            end select
        end if

    end do

end program mwe
```

But the code is crashing when attempting to read from a binary file with the following error:

```
forrtl: severe (67): input statement requires too much data, unit 123, file /home/martin/Desktop/test5.dat
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
test5              000000000040E28E  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
test5              000000000042A9F9  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
test5              0000000000407821  MAIN__                    131  test5.f90
test5              0000000000402ABE  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc-2.27.so       00007F15519BBB97  __libc_start_main     Unknown  Unknown
test5              00000000004029AA  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please compile with debugging flags (`-g -traceback -check`) to get meaningful backtraces. Now and for future questions. Also for yourself to make you rile easier.

Comment: @VladimirF Added "improved" error message

Comment: OK, I now find your `! ERROR` comment, but it was hard to find.

Comment: You are using defined output, but not defined input?  That is, why are you using `read(123) t%num, t%num2` rather than `read(123) t` much as you `write(123) t`?

Comment: @francescalus You're completely right, it was bascially a "typo" or, better said, a silly mistake. Write, please, your comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Apologies, I've actually lead you completely astray.  I'll explain in an answer.

Comment: This is really a duplicate of your [newer question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50774846/3157076).  I can't close as duplicate because of my previous "typo" vote.  The `read(123) t` works for the same reason as the bug in that question.  `read(123) t%num, t%num2` fails because the corresponding `write(123) t` wrote out only that value as though `t` were of type `a`.